Parse LDAP-URL to the hostname and Base-DN
I try to parse an LDAP-URL in Java.
import java.net.URL;

String url = "ldaps://my.ldap.site/o=test,dc=testdc,dc=us";
URL url = new URL (this.url);

But that brings an MalformedURLException up. Seems that URL does not know LDAP.
What I need is to find the host (my.ldap.site) and the base-DN (o=test,dc=testdc,dc=us).
Is there any class that does that for me or do I need to start a RegExp?

Use URI.create("ldaps://my.ldap.site/t/o=test,dc=testdc,dc=us");  And call ::getHost on that

And String path = u.getPath();String baseDN = path.substring(path.indexOf("o="));

Having said that though, you should probably be using a proper ldapsdk

Proper way:
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.migrate.ldapjdk.LDAPUrl;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LDAPUrl u = new LDAPUrl(args[0]);
        System.out.println(u.getHost());
        System.out.println(u.getDN());
    }
}

